# Can a sentence have no verb except in what would otherwise be its noun phrase?

Tags: verbs, sentence, ellipses, noun-phrases

Can a sentence have no verb except in what would otherwise be its noun phrase?

e.g.

- The car in the street I walk down.

I'm guessing that "the street I walk down" would be the noun phrase, and it contains a verb (walk). So I wondered whether that's sufficient for a sentence. I'm guessing not.

I think I mean (tortuously)

- I walk down the street the car is in.

What if the elided verb is more obvious?

- The bird in the air I breath.

That seems to be the case here (birds always seem to *fly* in the air)

- I breath the air the bird flies in.

---

So I think I'm asking about

1. **verb ellipsis** (the car [is] in), and
2. whether I can put objects first, both before its subject and verb (OBJECT I walk down), and
3. so that the object with an elided verb is before its subject (the car in SUBJECT).

3 could be an example of

> poetic hyperbaton "Answer gave he none", and "What say You?"

2 could be an example of an elided 'but'

> OSV... as a contrast with the conjunction but: "Rome I shall see!" and "Oranges I may hate; (but)* Apples I shall eat!".

I'm not sure these can be used together, or when verb ellipsis is reasonable.

In summary, are "The bird in the air I breath" or "I breath the air the bird in" complete sentences, and might either say the same as "I breath the air the bird flies in"?

Comment: No. Those aren’t sentences.  They are just noun phrases. Try dropping the nonessential elements of the sentence to get to its essence.  For example “The big red balloon flying over the church with the steeple just radioed for help” can be reduced to “The balloon radioed”  In your “sentence” you get “The bird” and “The car”

Comment: @Jim yeah i get that. i'm not *completely* sure you're right, only because you may have missed that i (think i) did use 'noun phrase' correctly in my question. and, if you did, that does not bode well, as i probably didn't explain myself

Comment: I suppose you could play with the "Rome I see" style (reminiscent of Yoda from Star Wars) to get "The car, I drive" and "The street, I walk". You'll need to be careful to avoid leaving the result as just a noun phrase, though.

Comment: ok @Lawrence oddly, for me, "the car is in the street i walk down" says exactly the same thing, for me, as "i walk down the street the car is in". not sure why?

Comment: "I breath the air the bird in" *almost* seems ok to me in informal speech.

Comment: You have made efforts both on Meta and here to ensure that you ask a good question and explain your line of thought. I think your question boils down to: _Are 'The car in the street I walk down' or 'The bird in the air I breath/I breath the air the bird in'  sentences?_. But the section you include after your words _So I think I'm asking about_ muddies the waters a bit for me.

Comment: ok just my own suggestions for an answer, should i edit it out @Shoe

Comment: I'll leave you to decide whether to edit it out. It may be helpful to other potential answerers. But perhaps you could end your post with an _In summary_ paragraph (e.g, In summary: _Are 'The car in the street I walk down', 'The bird in the air I breath', and 'I breath the air the bird in' complete sentences?_) to refocus on the main point of your post.

Comment: You do realise that in  "The car in the street [I walk down]",the bracketed element is a relative clause?

Comment: i think so! how does it matter? @BillJ i mean if it's possible to say what is a relative clause in a sentence fragment.

Comment: I don't see where there is an elided verb in  "The bird in the air I breath".

Comment: after the second word @BillJ it's not obviously so, at least if it's read as SVO

Comment: If "The bird in the air I breath" is intended to be an NP, then "in the air that I breathe" is a PP modifying "bird". No verb has been elided.

Comment: no it's not meant as a noun phrase, it's meant as a sentence or sentence fragment (that would be a NP if a NP could alone could make a sentence @BillJ

Answer (score 3):

Neither *The bird in the air I breathe* nor *I breathe the air the bird in* is a complete sentence.

*The bird in the air I breathe* is a postmodified noun phrase which cannot stand alone as a sentence. It can function as the subject of a sentence, for example:

- *The bird* in the air I breathe **is** a bluejay

or as the object:

- *My sister* **likes** the bird in the air I breathe.

The example sentences sound odd because the words *the bird in the air I breathe* are unlikely in any sensible context I can think of. But they are now complete sentences with a subject in italics and a predicate (verb) in bold.

*I breathe the air the bird in* is not a correct sentence. It contains a subject *I*, and predicate verb *breathe* together with an object *the air*. The object is postmodified by a finite restrictive relative clause (reduced by omitting the relative pronoun *that/which*). But since each finite clause must have a verb, and the verb is missing here, the 'sentence' is ungrammatical.

An example of a corrected version of the relative clause (adding the missing verb) is:

- I breathe the air the bird *flies* in.

Comment: could you edit in the fragments i used, rather than your (presumably illustrative) take on them?

Comment: You will need to specify which fragments you mean.

Comment: think you've done it now anyway, let me read... yeah you have. so you defninitely can't use verb ellipsis to interpret 'the bird in [the air I breath]'?

Comment: _The car in the street I walk down_ is exactly the same structure as _The bird in the air I breathe_, namely a postmodified noun phrase that can be the subject or object of a sentence. If a subject, then just a main verb is needed to complete the sentence. If an object, then both a subject and main verb are needed. And, you are right, '_the bird [in the air I breathe]_' is simply a noun phrase that tells us nothing about the verb that is needed to complete the sentence..